# UserForm ListBox Select Item and Got to Row

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching for an answer for the past 5 hours - no luck.
I am using a UserForm that has a ListBox listing cells that contain a specific value. All works good. However, I want to be able go to the row when clicking on the item listed within the ListBox.
Here is the code I'm using.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ListBox1.clear
ListBox1.List = Range("AQ3:AQ255").Value
Call List
End Sub

Private Sub List()
Dim i As Long
' loop backwards through items,
For i = ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    ' check each if it contains meaningful text
    If Trim(ListBox1.List(i) & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then
        ' if not, delete that item
        ListBox1.RemoveItem (i)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: braX, I have edited my original post to include the code I'm using. Not sure as to how and add the code you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden column to hold the row.

```vb
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    With ListBox1
        i = .ListIndex
        If i >= 0 Then
            r = ListBox1.List(i, 0)
            'Cells(r, "AQ").Select
            Rows(r).Select
            Me.Hide
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long, ar, n As Long
    ar = Range("AQ1:AQ255").Value
    With ListBox1
       .Clear
       .ColumnCount = 2
       .ColumnWidths = "0"
       
       For i = 3 To UBound(ar)
          If Len(ar(i, 1)) > 0 Then
             .AddItem
             .List(n, 0) = i
             .List(n, 1) = ar(i, 1)
             n = n + 1
          End If
       Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. However, when I click on a value, a MsgBox appears listing the row. I am wanting when a value is clicked, the UserForm hides and the row is highlighted. That way, changes can be made to the cell values.

Comment: CPD1802, thank you much!! I notice when I click on the value, it highlights the row. Is there a way to go to the row.

Comment: @BrentJohn do you mean a particular cell in the row

Comment: CPD1802 yes. I'm pulling the values from column AQ that are referencing the values from column I. Therefore, I would like to be able to go to the cell that is being click on in column I.

Comment: @BrentJohn replace the `Rows(r).Select` with `Cells(r, "I").Select`